# PostgreSQL - find highest value in two column table

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL. I have three tables:

```
Items(itemid, description, size, color)    
Inventory(storeid, itemid, qty)
Stores(storeid, city, managerid)
```

My task is to find retrieve the most common item size held in inventory by stores in Nashville. Here is the expected solution:

```
size
------
medium
small
```

Here is where I am at:

```
select size, count(size)
from items
join inventory using (itemid)
where storeid in (select storeid from stores where city = 'Nashville')
group by size;
```

Which yields

```
  size  | count 
--------+-------
 large  |     3
 medium |     4
 small  |     4
(3 rows)
```

I know I am close, but I am unsure how to just print out medium and small. I could hard code the above and add "having count(size) = 4," but would only match the output. I thought of making a temporary table and joining it to the query above to allow me to reference the max(count), but I haven't found a way that I can understand. I am not looking to blindly copy, I want to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with s as (
    select size, count(size) as size_count
    from
        items
        inner join
        inventory using (itemid)
        inner join
        stores using (storeid)
    where city = 'Nashville'
    group by size
)
select size, size_count
from s
where size_count = (select max(size_count) from s)
```

Comment: This yields the same table from the query that I posted above. Please see above.

Comment: @piofusco Check the new version